# Passing header from apache to proxy location

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, http-headers, environment-variables, remote-server

I have two Apache servers `Server1` and `Server2` running on hosts `Host1` and `Host2`. Both have SSL enabled. On `Host2`, there is another server `Server3` written in C listening on port 5555. This server listens only on the loopback interface (it listens only on the localhost i.e. `Host2`). I have added the following to the httpd.conf of `Server2`:

```
<Location /specialserver>
    ProxyPass  http://localhost:5555
    Order  allow,deny
    Allow  from all
    ProxyPassReverse  http://localhost:5555
</Location>
```

There is a website hosted on `Server1` which contains a link to `/specialserver` and various other links all of which are on `Server2`. I want to pass the values of REMOTE_USER and a couple of other environment variables to /specialserver. I cannot pass them as separate variables so I have to concatenate the values of the required environment variables and pass them as a single variable. For this, I have added the following `mod_rewrite` commands in httpd.conf files of `Server1` and `Server2`:

```
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER}*%{REMOTE_ADDR}*%{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule (.*) - [E=X-REMOTE_INFO:%1]
```

This concatenates the environment variables and assigns the result to an environment variable named `X-REMOTE_INFO`. Also, I have modified the Location block to add this value to the request header like this:

```
<Location /specialserver>
    ProxyPass  http://localhost:5555
    Order  allow,deny
    Allow  from all
    ProxyPassReverse  http://localhost:5555
    RequestHeader  merge X-REMOTE_INFO %{X-REMOTE_INFO}e
</Location>
```

I know that the value of REMOTE_USER on `Server2` is correct (I checked the value). My custom header and my custom environment variable also have the correct values (REMOTE_USER*REMOTE_ADDR*QUERY_STRING). However, my environment variable loses the value of REMOTE_USER when it reaches `Server3`. Instead of having the value as REMOTE_USER*REMOTE_ADDR*QUERY_STRING now it just has *REMOTE_ADDR*QUERY_STRING. The value of REMOTE_USER is no longer available in X-REMOTE_INFO. I have tried changing `merge` to `add` and `set`. I have also tried without the look-ahead (i.e. without `LA:U`). The value is still lost. It looks like the value of X-REMOTE_INFO is being calculated again when the link to /specialserver is clicked. `Server3` does not have the value of REMOTE_USER and hence the value is empty. How do I pass the value of X-REMOTE_INFO as it appears on `Server2` to `Server3`?

My requirement is to pass the values of REMOTE_USER, REMOTE_ADDR and QUERY_STRING from `Server2` to `Server3` as a single variable. I have done all this to fulfil this requirement.

1. Any help to achieve what I want using my method is welcome.
2. Any other methods are welcome.